# controllerAs vs $scope - writing, testing and performance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm building a relatively large application using angular and we're currently doing planning and testing.  One thing we're undecided on is controllerAs or classic $scope when writing controllers.  We're going to us a Service Model Locator so every single controller will have some injected dependencies.

I've built out a sample controller using both methods - I guess my questions are
1. what is the right/better approach
2. Is there another way to inject using controllerAs
3. Is there a performance difference and a good way to test this?

thanks in advance

Greg

Classic $scope method

```
angular.module('sdt.settingsctrl', [])
    .controller('SettingsCtrl', ['$scope','$log', 'ModalService','SettingsModel', function ($scope, $log, ModalService, SettingsModel) {
        $scope.data = SettingsModel.getData();
        $scope.settings = SettingsModel.settings()

        $scope.open = function(){
            var items = [{item:'item1'},{item: 'item2'},{item: 'item3'}];
            var modalOptions = {
                closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
                actionButtonText: 'OK',
                headerText: 'Adjust your settings',
                bodyText: items,
                result: $scope.callBack(),

                //optional - if you use this option feel free to
                //add more properties to work with your custom template
                template: 'partials/modals/settings.html'
            }


            ModalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
                $log.log(result);
            });
        }

        $scope.callBack = function() {
            return SettingsModel.settings();
        }
    }])
```

ControllerAs method

```
angular.module('sdt.settingsctrl', [])
 .controller('SettingsCtrl', SettingsCtrl);

SettingsCtrl.$inject= ['$log', 'ModalService', 'SettingsModel'];

function SettingsCtrl($log, ModalService, SettingsModel){
    angular.extend(this, {
        data: SettingsModel.getData(),
        settings: SettingsModel.settings(),
        open:  function() {
            var items = [{item: 'item1'}, {item: 'item2'}, {item: 'item3'}];
            var modalOptions = {
                closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
                actionButtonText: 'OK',
                headerText: 'Adjust your settings',
                bodyText: items,
                result: this.callBack(),

                //optional - if you use this option feel free to
                //add more properties to work with your custom template
                template: 'partials/modals/settings.html'
            }


            ModalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
                $log.log(result);
            })
        },
        callBack: function() {
            return SettingsModel.settings();
        }
    })

};
```

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found the question of which way to go: ControllerAs vs. $scopeto be flawed. The two approaches are not meant to be equivalent or interchangeable, so it's a bit of misnomer to call one "classic".

- `$scope` is meant to be used to declare ViewModel properties that are
  visible in the scope hierarchy - both to the View and to the child
  controllers. Child controllers access scope properties set by the parent via $scope.
- `ControllerAs` paradigm makes it easy to treat the Controller itself
  as a ViewModel and restricts the ViewModel's visibility from child
  controllers. Child controllers have no easy way of accessing the parent's controller's scope.

I use the following convention to distinguish scope-exposed properties from controller-exposed properties:

```
var VM = $scope.VM = ($scope.VM || {}); // scope-exposed
var vm = this; // controller-exposed
```

Consider the following:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as vm">
  {{vm.parentsProp}}
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
     {{VM.scopeProp}}
     {{vm.childProp}}
     {{vm.parentsProp}} - not visible
  </div>
</div>

app.controller("ParentCtrl", function($scope) {
  var VM = $scope.VM = ($scope.VM || {});
  var vm = this;

  vm.parentsProp = "parentsProp";
  VM.scopeProp = "scopePropSetInParent";
});

app.controller("ChildCtrl", function($scope) {
  var VM = $scope.VM = ($scope.VM || {});
  var vm = this;

  vm.childProp = VM.scopeProp + " - augmented by Child";
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MZhKvdC10SBt4llSdJBm?p=preview)

===

As an additional point, `ControllerAs` provides another capability of accessing controllers' ViewModels via alias (rather than less robust `$parent`) It is a powerful feature, but be careful since it can create a spaghetti-code in the View:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as pvm">
   <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as cvm">
      {{pvm.prop1 + cvm.prop2}}
   </div>
</div>
```